# Multiple DDNS with one public IP

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, ssl, nas

I need a bit of help with what I have setup and direction if am doing anything wrong . 
So I have two dynamic dns names :

PC1.dyndns.org port forwarded to my one pc at home 192.168.0.50:3389 for remote desktop login
the second name pcnas.dyndns.org setup for my ssl cert for my nas forwarded to nas box 192.168.0.10:5001 
now everything is working fine the only issue i came across the other day by coincidence is that I browsed to https://pc1.dyndns.org:5001 which took me to the NAS login page with SSL cert on browser not being secure. 
How can I get this setup so I don't reach the NAS login page when doing the above.
In another words how to keep two dynamic dns names separate under one Public IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't keep them 100% separate. The server doesn't know which domain name was used until *after* it has accepted the TCP connection and started the TLS negotiation.

If your only public services are HTTPS-based or at least TLS-based (like RDP), then you can keep the domains 90% separate by configuring a default VirtualHost on your NAS web service that just shows a blank page. (In Apache or Nginx it just needs to be the first/topmost vhost.)

However, you **cannot** prevent the NAS from accepting the connection in general. Most webservers unfortunately also don't have an option to avoid the certificate warning – if the NAS doesn't have a cert for the domain they'll just use the first cert they have, instead of ending the connection right there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes unfortunately i've been told it can be difficult to stop this happening. Most services don't bother checking for anything but that the port they listen to receives something.

Comment: They check quite a bit. An HTTP service expects that "something" to always be a properly formatted HTTP request, and so on. The problem is that the domain name cannot be determined _until after_ something has been received – and in addition to that, _only_ HTTP or TLS clients send that domain name in the first place. Other client apps like SSH or Minecraft simply don't, so there's nothing a service could check anyway.

Comment: what is the security implication of this? And if there is any changes or recommendations. And just keep logging in to the NAS using the configured HTTPS method and ignore the other way.